# How to create a default configuration for each (new) Jenkins job?

Tags: jenkins, default

During my long use of Jenkins I have come up with a set of defaults which I use for each new job, such as:

- using [Workspace Cleanup Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Workspace+Cleanup+Plugin) to clean workspace before each build,
- adding timestamps to the Console Output,
- using the same SCM viewer

etc.

..but for now I set them up manually/copy an existing job as a template for a new one but that is obviously non-optimal.

I have looked for a plugin/setting that would enable me to configure the default setting for new jobs/global job settings that would override each job settings but I haven't found any solution yet.

**Do you know how to do it?**

## Update

I have looked at [Configuration Slicing Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Configuration+Slicing+Plugin) but it's not clear to me whether this will help..

## Update 2

I have just been reminded of [Jenkins Job DSL / Plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin) and I will look into its features soon but I am still interested in a simpler solution, with a lower entry level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the [Job DSL](https://github.com/JeremyMarshall/angular-fullstack-dist.git) which does the Dev Ops 'configuration as code' by building out your jobs (using another job)

```
The Jenkins "Job DSL / Plugin" is made up of two parts: The Domain
Specific Language (DSL) itself that allows users to describe jobs 
using a Groovy-based language, and a Jenkins plugin which manages 
the scripts and the updating of the Jenkins jobs which are created 
and maintained as a result.
```

Alternatively, the new way to do it is to define a [pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/) (Jenkins 2.0)
Which is a `Jenkinsfile` in the root of your repo

```
Jenkins Pipeline is a suite of plugins which supports implementing 
and integrating continuous delivery pipelines into Jenkins. Pipeline
provides an extensible set of tools for modelling simple-to-complex
delivery pipelines "as code" via the Pipeline DSL.
```

Comment: I wouldn't recomend the Job DSL for a noob.  It should use jenkins pipline

Answer (score 0):

The way I do this is by creating jobs with default options which only serve as templates. Then when creating a new job I select the option "Copy from" and write the name of the template job.

An even better solution would be to use something like inheritance - have a parent job which other jobs inherit, so if you want to add an option to all the jobs you would just need to add it to the parent job. The [Inheritance plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/inheritance-plugin) seems to do this, but unfortunately for me it interferes with other plugins and crashes when trying to configure it.